# Chrome opens succesfully from terminal but I get webdriver common exception message

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I receive selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/google-chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was : 0

For background, this is a Linux system and I am typing all the information in the terminal. I looked at many questions. A lot of them recommending uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome. I did that several times. I typed in whereis Google Chrome and found the location. I did not get a .exe file though so I used "/usr/bin/google-chrome". Linux doesn't appear to create a .exe file. I am bringing this up because I am not sure if this contributed to my error.

This is after I typed in 
my_path = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=my_path)

I get many lines of responses on the terminal referencing files in my python3.6 library. Before the main error of it saying it exited unexpectedly, I get

"file "home/ganesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py, line 73 in **init**"
"file "home/ganesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py, line 98 in start"

The thing is that my terminal successfully opens the Chrome browser. However, I get the webdriver exception message I had.

In addition, the code ,
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=my_path)

clearly didn't fully work because later in the program when I type in 
browser.(something else), it doesn't work and says "name 'browser' is not define"

I am hoping for the webdriver exception error to be resolved and for me to successfully be able to call browser in my code later on

This question is not a duplicate as marked by someone here. The question that he referred to as answering my question does not answer my question - in that version Chrome exited. In mine, Chrome did not exit, it stayed open. In addition, the previous question has solutions in Windows and Mac, but not for Linux which is my operating system.
It is my first week using Linux.

Comment: This is now resolved. Using my_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver" worked
I had been using a lot of whereis googlechrome instead of whereis chromedriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. If the chromedriver file is located in `/usr/bin/google-chrome` folder then your `my_path` should be `my_path = "/usr/bin/google-chrome/chromedriver"`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I now get a 'Not a Directory Error" Errno 20. Not a directory
I do not have a chromedriver file. Not sure if this is normal of if that files goes by a different name in my system

Comment: Do you have `google-chrome` folder under `/usr/bin`?

Comment: No, I do not have a folder, just a single file.
Calling the google-chrome actually successfully starts the CHrome browser. Just for some reason, I get the error later when I try to call the browser and can't do anything else with it. It's almost as though it is called, but not done properly

Comment: hmm, confused how browser is launching. Did you renamed the chromedriver to `google-chrome`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. A small tweak to what you suggested work. When I did my_path - "usr/bin/chromedriver", it worked.